# Update MemberType property based on dropdown list select value

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have created a property under a MemberType called "testField" which is using a custom DataType dropdown list with 2 values in it (Employee and Subcontractor). I would like for a member to be able to select one, submit a form and to store their selection under this property, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Is it possible to do this whilst being able to change their selection manually in the back end?

Here's my code...

ASCX

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Register.ascx.cs" Inherits="nForum.usercontrols.nForum.membership.Register" %>

    <div id="forumregistration" class="validate">
            <dl class="form">
                <dt><label for="<%= tbLoginName.ClientID %>">Login/Username:</label></dt>
                <dd><asp:TextBox ToolTip="Enter username" CssClass="required" ID="tbLoginName" runat="server" /></dd>

                <dt><label for="<%= tbName.ClientID %>">Full Name:</label></dt>
                <dd><asp:TextBox ToolTip="Enter name" CssClass="required" ID="tbName" runat="server" /></dd>

                <dt><label for="<%= tbEmail.ClientID %>">Email:</label></dt>
                <dd><asp:TextBox ToolTip="Enter email address" CssClass="required email" ID="tbEmail" runat="server" /></dd>

                <dt><label for="<%= tbPassword.ClientID %>">Password:</label></dt>
                <dd><asp:TextBox ToolTip="Enter a password" CssClass="required password" ID="tbPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" /></dd>

                <dt><label for="">Status:</label></dt>
                <asp:dropdownlist ID="tbOrganisation" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Choose" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Employee" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Subcontractor" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:dropdownlist>
                <dt> </dt>
                <dd><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="textarea" runat="server" Text="Create Account" onclick="BtnSubmitClick" /></dd>

            </dl>
    </div>
```

CS

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Security;
using nForum.BusinessLogic;
using umbraco;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member;

namespace nForum.usercontrols.nForum.membership
{
    public partial class Register : BaseForumUsercontrol
    {

        protected void BtnSubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var redirecturl = Settings.Url;

            // Check the user isn't already registered
            if (Member.GetMemberFromEmail(Helpers.GetSafeHtml(tbEmail.Text)) == null & Member.GetMemberFromLoginName(Helpers.GetSafeHtml(tbLoginName.Text)) == null)
            {
                // Set the member type and group
                var mt = MemberType.GetByAlias(MembershipHelper.ForumUserRoleName);
                var addToMemberGroup = MemberGroup.GetByName(MembershipHelper.ForumUserRoleName);

                //create a member
                var m = Member.MakeNew(Helpers.GetSafeHtml(tbName.Text), mt, new umbraco.BusinessLogic.User(0));

                //var mstatus = new MembershipCreateStatus();
                //var mp = Membership.CreateUser(tbName.Text, tbPassword.Text, tbEmail.Text, string.Empty, string.Empty, true, out mstatus);

                // Set the other properties
                m.Email = Helpers.GetSafeHtml(tbEmail.Text);
                m.LoginName = Helpers.GetSafeHtml(tbLoginName.Text);
                m.Password = Helpers.GetSafeHtml(tbPassword.Text);
                // Add 0 Karma to user, helps us later in the site
                m.getProperty("forumUserKarma").Value = 0;
                m.getProperty("forumUserAllowPrivateMessages").Value = 1;
                m.getProperty("forumUserLastPrivateMessage").Value = DateTime.Now;

                // Take selected dropdown value and store
                m.getProperty("testField").Value = tbOrganisation;

                //##### Manual Member Authorisation #####
                // If this is not enabled, mark the member as authorised
                if (!Settings.ManuallyAuthoriseNewMembers)
                {
                    m.getProperty("forumUserIsAuthorised").Value = 1;
                }

                m.AddGroup(addToMemberGroup.Id);

                //Save member
                m.Save();

                //Generate member Xml Cache
                m.XmlGenerate(new System.Xml.XmlDocument());

                if (!Settings.ManuallyAuthoriseNewMembers)
                {
                    //Login the user so they can be redirected to their profile page
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tbLoginName.Text, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    redirecturl = string.Concat(CurrentPageAbsoluteUrl, "?m=", library.GetDictionaryItem("NotifiedWhenAccountAuth"));
                }

                // If admins wants email notification, then send it here
                if (Settings.EmailAdminOnNewMemberSignUp)
                {
                    SendAdminNotification(m);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                redirecturl = string.Concat(CurrentPageAbsoluteUrl, "?m=", library.GetDictionaryItem("UserAlreadyExists"));
            }

            // Now redirect to the correct page
            Response.Redirect("/discuss-it");

        }

        private void SendAdminNotification(Member newmember)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat(library.GetDictionaryItem("MemberSignUpEmailText"),
                Settings.Name,
                newmember.LoginName,
                newmember.Text,
                newmember.Email);
            Helpers.SendMail(Settings.EmailNotification, Settings.EmailAdmin, library.GetDictionaryItem("NewMemberSignUp"), sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `m.getProperty("testField").Value = tbOrganisation;` is setting the value to the DropDownList not to the `SelectedValue` of the DropDownList.

Comment: Thanks Dave, do I just need to store the SelectedValue and then send it off to the property then?

Comment: Probably, it depends on the data type of that property. If it expects and is happy with a plain old string value (which most are) then yes.

Comment: I think this is my problem. I'm trying to save the value into my drop down list Member Type property and it doesn't seem to be changing anything in the back end. http://oi59.tinypic.com/9fvfo6.jpg

Comment: Do the values in your `tbOrganisation` DropDownList correspond to the equivalent values in the `testField` datatype?

Comment: Oh god... I was using different values/IDs and that's why it wasn't changing! It's working now, thanks so much Dave. :) I just had to change value 1 and 2, to match the values in my prevalues.

Comment: Consider binding your DropDownList to the PreValues to avoid this and automatically account for any changes in the future [see this blog for how to implement](http://blog.dampee.be/post/2012/04/15/Get-a-prevalues-dropdownlist-in-Razor-(umbraco)-for-a-datatype.aspx)

Comment: @DaveParsons why not give an answer - as you've clearly cracked the problem

Comment: @amelvin: indeed I should this is a Q & **A** site after all :)

Comment: @DaveParsons good answer, should attract some upvotes (probably take a while given that people seem stingier on upvoting these days on SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific issue is two fold:

1) You are setting `m.getProperty("testField")` to the instance of the `DropDownList` 
rather than to it's `SelectedValue`

2) As noted in the comments on the question you had a mis-match in your hardcoded `DropDownList` values
and the values stored in the Umbraco `DataType` for the `testField` property.

You can address the second issue more robustly by binding your `DropDownList` with what Umbraco calls
the `PreValues` stored on the `testField` DataType is will ensure the available options in the `DropDownList`
match the options defined on the `DataType`

As of writing this `PreValues` are stored as an XML fragment on the datatype definition in 
the following format:

```
<preValues>
    <preValue id="1">Option 1</preValue>
    <preValue id="2">Option 2</preValue>
    <preValue id="3">Option 3</preValue>
</preValues>
```

To retrieve these programmatically is a little clunky (IMO); You first you have to obtain the `Id` of `DataType` by
mousing over the `DataType` in the umbraco interface and looking in the status bar (you should see something like `javascript:openDataType(1111)` where `1111` is the `Id`.

Next call the `umbraco.library.GetPreValues()` method, passing in the `Id` obtained above. This method
returns an `XPathNodeIterator` which you can use to get the values in whichever way suits your need such as creation of a `Dictionary<string,string>` which you can bind to your `DropDownList`. The following example is taken from [Damiaan Peeters blog](http://blog.dampee.be/post/2012/04/15/Get-a-prevalues-dropdownlist-in-Razor-%28umbraco%29-for-a-datatype.aspx)
and adapted ever so slightly.

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> GetPreValues(int dataTypeId)
{
    XPathNodeIterator preValueRootElementIterator = umbraco.library.GetPreValues(dataTypeId);
    preValueRootElementIterator.MoveNext(); //move to first 
    XPathNodeIterator preValueIterator = preValueRootElementIterator.Current.SelectChildren("preValue", "");
    var retVal = new Dictionary<int, object>();

    while (preValueIterator.MoveNext())        
        retVal.Add(preValueIterator.Current.GetAttribute("id", ""), preValueIterator.Current.Value);

    return retVal;
}
```

Then in your code behind you can do the following:

```
tbOrganisation.DataSource = GetPreValues(1111);
tbOrganisation.DataTextField = "Value";
tbOrganisation.DataValueField = "Key";
tbOrganisation.DataBind();
```

Comment: Once again, completely fool-proof. Thanks for taking the time to help out.